# Android GestureDetector onScroll unexpected behavior

Tags: android, distance, gesture, repeat

I have `SimpleGestureDetectorListener` and implemented `onScroll` as follows:

```
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,     float distanceY)
    {
        Log.i("MOVE_LARGE", "e1.getY=" + e1.getY()+" "+"e2.getY="+e2.getY());
        Log.i("MOVE_SMALL", "distanceY=" + distanceY);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)      fragmentContainer.getLayoutParams();
        int nextMargin = params.topMargin - (int) distanceY;
        if (Math.abs(distanceY )> MOVE_TRESHOLD)
        {
            setContainerMargin(nextMargin);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

As you might guess, i move some view. So when i move it at some point when I stop my finger on screen, view starts jumping back and forth.

I have logged events and have such picture:

```
   03-09 10:57:02.874: I/MOVE_EVENT(27478): 2
   03-09 10:57:02.875: I/MOVE_LARGE(27478): e1.getY=24.892685 e2.getY=261.41266
   03-09 10:57:02.875: I/MOVE_SMALL(27478): distanceY=23.0
   03-09 10:57:02.891: I/MOVE_EVENT(27478): 2
   03-09 10:57:02.892: I/MOVE_LARGE(27478): e1.getY=24.892685 e2.getY=284.41266
   03-09 10:57:02.892: I/MOVE_SMALL(27478): distanceY=-23.0
   03-09 10:57:02.908: I/MOVE_EVENT(27478): 2
   03-09 10:57:02.908: I/MOVE_LARGE(27478): e1.getY=24.892685 e2.getY=261.41266
   03-09 10:57:02.908: I/MOVE_SMALL(27478): distanceY=23.0
   03-09 10:57:02.925: I/MOVE_EVENT(27478): 2
   03-09 10:57:02.925: I/MOVE_LARGE(27478): e1.getY=24.892685 e2.getY=284.41266
   03-09 10:57:02.925: I/MOVE_SMALL(27478): distanceY=-23.0
   03-09 10:57:02.941: I/MOVE_EVENT(27478): 2
```

And it keeps repeating if I don't move the finger. Treshold is not the problem, because distance varies widely (from 10 to 100). Event is 2==ACTION_MOVE.

**What is the problem and how to work around it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the problem is that I was trying to move some view and I assigned touch listener (not intentionally) to view that was being moved. So that is what caused my "unexpected behavior".